# Why is the "this" keyword final in Java?

Tags: java, final

It seems a thing that almost no one has realized, but the "this reference" in Java is final. In a normal programming day I thought I could redefine the entire instance by redefining the this reference inside the own class:

```
public void method() {
    this = new MyObject("arg1", arg2, arg3); //it throws a compile error
}
```

Why the this reference is final in Java?

Comment: to prevent people from writing such code.

Comment: `It seems a thing that almost no one has realized` Everyone who writes a real program in Java will have realized this.

Comment: final is only about the reference and it is not about the contents of the referenced object.

Comment: 'this' is keyword not variable and you can not assign something to keyword. That's all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not that `this` is a `final` reference - it's not itself a reference at all. `this` is a *keyword* that "denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method or default method was invoked" ([JLS §15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)).

Furthermore, it wouldn't make sense to reassign it in the sense that a variable can be reassigned. Remember that reassigning a reference changes only that reference, and not other references that might point to the same object. So reassigning `this` would not only be insane but also useless.

Comment: _+1 you can't instantiate keyword in java full stop_

Answer (score 2):

I find this question interesting from a theoretical point of view.

From a technical point of view this cannot work, as in Java we have pass-refererence-by-value ( http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html ) and cannot swap out objects where some other parts of code hold a reference to that object -- i.e. a true swap method is not possible in Java (see the linked article).

While you could theoretically reassign `this`, all other references to the object would not change and make the operation pretty senseless.

The closest thing you can achieve is a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a variable you can assign a value to. It is a built-in expression returning the object that is the context for the method currently executing.

While re-assigning `this` might be useful for some nice hacks, it would mess up all kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword is used to provide a reference to the current object within its class. Mostly, it is used to clarify scope issues with local variables which have the same identifier as a class member. E.g.

```
public void function (int param) {
   this.param = param   
}
```

Reassigning it to another object goes beyond the task assigned to the keyboard. What you want to do, (reassing a reference) can be achieved on the upper context, i.e. the context in which the object was created (and a reference to it was assigned).

Answer (score 0):

Wrong thinking about `this`. `this` is just a keyword(not variable) in java which referenced to current instance and its a compilation restriction that keyword(any not only `this`) can not be initialized.